# android ListView hide position 0 until scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

what i want is to hide the first position when creating the list

but if the user scrolls the list to up show the hidden item

i tried this to hide the first item after creating the list but some times the list just have tow items so its not scrolling How can i achieve that?

```
listview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listview.setSelection(1);
    }
});
```

the list can at least have to rows.

Comment: How can it be scrolled when the `sum of list items height` is lesser than the height of `listview`. You need to figure alternative logic for this, or reduce the height to less than height of one element. I prefer the earlier than later

Comment: you can put the first item as Header, then increase/decrease the Header's height.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is skip the first element in your adapter, and when ListView is scrolled switch the old items with the new ones (including the first item). E.g.:

```
final List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

List<String> itemsFirstSkipped = items.subList(1, items.size()-1);

final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
        itemsFirstSkipped);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // Make sure at least 1 item is scrolled
        if (firstVisibleItem>0) {
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(items);
            // notifyDataSetChanged is called by default
        }
    }
});
```